# What should my Rails routes look like to work with pushState Ember.js routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes, ember-data

**In short...**

When building an Ember.js app to persist to a Rails app, how should I handle Rails routing/views? I would think I just need Rails to render the application.html.erb layout so the Ember.js app initializes and handles the routing/view/templates.

**Details:**

Specifically if I visit ***localhost:3000***, before my Ember.js app has a chance to initialize, Rails hits the "index" action on the *projects* controller. It will complain about a missing index template. I have no index.html.erb view as my Ember.js app has a view/template for it.

Should I be creating blank views for the Rails app? Should my Rails controller actions be returning something to prevent it from rendering a view? Or am I expected to build normal Rails views to go alongside the Ember.js app views/templates?

If I create a blank projects/index.html.erb and visit ***localhost:3000***, Rails will render it, Ember.js will initialize and handle routing from then on. However, if I visit ***localhost:3000/projects/new*** directly Rails complains about not having a new action in the projects controller. I do not have "new" action on the *projects* controller on the Rails side as I don't need it. My Ember.js app is handling that view/template.

Ultimately I'm just unsure of what convention is expected to use Ember.js along side a Rails app.

Thank you for the help and reading this far...

**Edit:**

I left out the detail that I'm attempting to use the Ember.js Router's ability to use [pushState](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.HistoryLocation&src=false) history. This would leave me non-hashbang URL's. This is one reason why I'm having issues dealing with Rails competing to route my application.

**Rails Application Layout:**

```
<html> 
<body>   
  <section id="design-archive"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Ember.js App:**

```
@DA = Em.Application.create
  name: 'Design Archive'
  VERSION: '0.1'
  rootElement: '#design-archive'
  ApplicationController: Em.Controller.extend()
  ApplicationView: Em.View.extend
    templateName: 'application'

DA.initialize(DA.Router)
```

**Rails Routes:**

```
DesignArchive::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :clients, :only => [:new, :create, :index, :show, :destroy]
  resources :projects, :only => [:new, :create, :index, :show, :destroy]

  root :to => 'projects#index'
end
```

**Ember.js Routes:**

```
DA.Router = Em.Router.create
  location: 'history'

  root: Em.Route.extend
    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      redirectsTo: 'projects'

    # Actions
    doProjects: (router) ->
      router.transitionTo('projects')
    doProjectsNew: (router) ->
      router.transitionTo('newProject')

    # Routes
    projects: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects'
      index: Em.Route.extend
        router: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('projects', DA.Project.find())
      showProject: Em.Route.transitionTo('project')

    project: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects/:project_id'
      connectOutlets: (router, project) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('project', project)
      projectsIndex: Em.Route.transitionTo('projects')

    newProject: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects/new'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('projectsNew')
```

**Rails Controller:**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @projects }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another update: I've since started using [DockYard's tutorial method](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ember/2013/01/07/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-api-part-1.html) for handling my Rails routes for a pushState Ember.js application. Here's an example Rails `routes.rb`:

```
EmberApp::Application.routes.draw do
    class FormatTest
      attr_accessor :mime_type

      def initialize(format)
        @mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(format)
      end

      def matches?(request)
        request.format == mime_type
      end
    end

    get '*foo', :to => 'ember#index', :constraints => FormatTest.new(:html)
    get '/', :to => 'ember#index', :constraints => FormatTest.new(:html)
end
```

Comment: I'm doing `:constraints => { :format => 'html' }` instead of defining a custom constraint object. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Answer (score 6):

You can have a catch-all route which bootstraps your Ember app.

Here's a simplified example from one of my apps:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/login"   => "sessions#new",     :via => :get, :as => :login
  match "/login"   => "sessions#create",  :via => :post
  match "/logout"  => "sessions#destroy", :via => :post, :as  => :logout

  match "/attachments/:id" => "attachments#download"
  match "/avatars/:id"     => "avatars#show"

  root :to => 'pages#bootstrap'

  # anything not matched by the above should be served the bootstrap
  match "/*path" => "pages#bootstrap"
end
```

This has the downside of returning `200` success instead of `404` errors when going to completely invalid URLs, as the Rails app doesn't know anything about the URL structure of the Ember app.

If you wanted to avoid that you could replicate your Ember URL structure in the routes and just point everything valid through to the bootstrap route instead of using the catch-all.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592804/respond-to-all-html-requests-with-layout) on responding to all HTML request with a specific layout. It is what I'm currently using and seems to work well. The only limitation would be that I could no longer have any non-Ember.js driven normal HTML views. For instance, I could not have user_session login/logout forms outside of Ember. I suppose I'll cross that bridge when if I get there.

I'm still not sure if this is the best way to handle my original problem, but below is my current setup. *home/show.html.erb* is a blank Rails view.

**Controllers:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :render_default_view

  private
    def render_default_view
      return if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'home/show' }
      end
    end
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
DesignArchive::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects, :only => [:new, :index, :show]

  namespace :api do
    resources :projects, :only => [:create, :index, :show, :destroy]
  end

  root :to => 'home#show'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have only one controller with one action for rendering an empty view, which just initialize your Ember application (an `HomeController` for example).

Then, this is the Ember router that must manage routes (all routes starting with `#/`).

Consequently, all other Rails routes are just an API (used by your Ember app), which return some JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @louiscoquio. I left out one bit of information, and that is that I'm trying to use Ember.js' Router ability to use pushState history. I suppose this may be the reason I'm running into issues with Rails attempting to route my app. I'll update my post. http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.HistoryLocation&src=false