# Ember - is "location: none" the only change needed to make a single-page app?

Tags: ember.js

I had been investigating ways to make my app a single-page app, and was considering using StateManager when I was told in one other question I posted in StackOverFlow that the Router approach is the latest Ember style. After lots of attempts, I stumbled upon "location: none" option in Router definition and using that my app's screens are no longer directly accessible. I am still using routes because of Router, but  is it true to assume that my app has indeed become single-page Ember app due to this one change alone? Or what other attributes of single-page do I need to configure to make it truly single-page Ember app?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Let's define what a Single Page Application (SPA) is. In the days when PHP and ASP.NET ruled the internet, web servers would dish out static pages that had static contents. If a user wanted to navigate to a different page, then they would have to ask the server for a completely different page to get the different content.

In the age of Javascript and modern browsers, we don't need our web servers to dish out a different page every time we want to view new content. Content is dynamic, and Javascript allows us to replace parts of a page without the server ever doing anything. That's the key with an SPA, there's no rules and bits of code that defines it. It's a single page that a server gives the user initially, and then the user asks for the *content* rather than a different page.

So, if your application only serves a single page, and the content is injected or taken away without requesting another page from the server, then you can consider it a SPA. In most projects that use this design you will see that they have only an 'index.html' page, and everything else is javascript files and template files. That's all it means to be a SPA.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: it doesn't really matter; using the router to manage client side state will make any Ember app a 'single page app'**

Almost by definition an Ember.js app using the router is 'single page' -- like what Deif said, 'single page' basically means there's one initial request for the request (html + js + css), the javascript Ember app is then initialized client side, and navigating around in the Ember app will cause different views to render / states to change / data to be displayed (the server returns data to be displayed by the client-side EmberJS app, instead of content wrapped in HTML), but it's all in the same initial page.

This might be confusing with the `location` setting. By default, Ember appends a `/#` to the URI, followed with the route path. You'll notice that when you're navigating around (via route transitions), the fragment after the `#` will change -- but **this is still all on the same page** so it counts as "single page app."

So what happens when you click the 'back' button? When each request is returns a new HTML page form the server, it's obvious: clicking 'back' takes your browser to the previous page  by repeating the GET request. But what about in a javascript app? Traditional JS single page apps can 'break' the back button -- you might navigate around, changing the state on the client side, but hitting the back button returns you to the previous website instead of instead of the previous 'page' of your single page app!

**Ember gets around the broken back button problem with the router + history location implementation -- setting `location` offers different behaviors.** I *think* `location:none` completely disables history -- I will try it later.

See: [EmberJS History Location](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.HistoryLocation.html)
and [What should my Rails routes look like to work with pushState Ember.js routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116804/what-should-my-rails-routes-look-like-to-work-with-pushstate-ember-js-routes)  and [EmberJS Routing Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/)

Comment: I have two questions regarding 'location: history' in Ember.js: <p> '1. Why do I have to specify "rootURL" in Router - otherwise the first page is not rendered? Worse still, I had to hard-code the app-name to make this work? Am I missing something or is this a drawback of Ember.js history feature? It simply said the /<app> URL is undefined, if I did not specify 'rootURL : /<app>' in Router.reopen?' 2

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle / example / code sample of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I tried a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tv_sathish/A8Qwb/10/), but it is not giving me any output? I am new to JSFiddle, not sure what mistake I am making, also I have not pasted my app, as is, just put the parts resembling my code and relevant to my issue at hand, please help. Please note that in the jsFiddle, I have not set rootURL to show the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md has some good instructions for setting up a JSfiddle with ember -- give that a shot? (See the "Reporting a bug" section")

Comment: Please refer [here](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/37/edit) for a sample, the rootURL feature is forcing to hard code the app URL and secondly every transition is a separate URL that is not bookmark-able as it results in a 404 page.

Comment: The reason Ember needs the rootURL attribute is because you're using `location: history` and JSBin is serving the result in an iframe with a root url Ember isn't expecting. For instance, I had to change `rootURL` in your sample to `'/_display/'` to get it to work in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkMAP/1/). I don't have much experience with `location: history` beyond that, so I can't say how this corresponds to its behavior in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Sherwin Yu and Deif are both correct. To add to what's already been stated, the reason why the default implementation of location (namely [HashLocation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.HashLocation.html)) maintains your application as a SPA is due to a particular property of [fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which is well summed up in [section 4 of this blog post](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/). (Ironically, that post doesn't utilize fragment ids, so I can't link you directly to the section in question.)

Take a look around [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GkMAP/). You might notice one of the major advantages of using the hash implementation:

```
<a href="#/third">third template</a>
```

Bookmark-able links directly to specific routes in your application work without any fuss.

I think what may be going on here is this: a lot of SPA frameworks out there don't offer anything like Ember's router location. With them, once you load the page, the url never changes. Thus, when Ember starts playing with the browser history and you see the url changing, it's natural to question whether this thing you've built is still an SPA. (It threw me off at first, too!) Rest assured it *is* an SPA. If it makes you more comfortable, use `location: 'none'` to keep that single page aesthetic; Ember won't care, but your users might. ;)